# Select rows between two DatetimeIndex that are part of a MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

idx_str = [
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'red',
    'red',
    'red',
]
idx_date = [
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10'),
]
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(idx_str, idx_date, data),
    columns=['idx_str', 'idx_dates', 'data'],
)
df.set_index([idx_str, idx_date], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

```bash
print(df)
                 data
blue 2010-01-01     1
     2010-01-05     2
     2010-01-06     3
     2010-01-10     4
red  2010-01-01     5
     2010-01-05     6
     2010-01-06     7
     2010-01-10     8
```

I'd like query rows that are between two dates of `datetimeIndex` level and limited to the color `red` of the first level

so I'd like this:

```bash
                  data
red   2010-01-02     5
      2010-01-03     6
```

because of the multiindex I can't use the solution i found such as

```py
df.query("'2010-01-02' <= index <= '2010-01-09'")
```

```py
df.loc['2010-01-02':'2010-01-09']
```

*May be it wasn't so clear the first time so I edited the end result I wanted*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first slice `(slice(None), slice(start_date, end_date))` corresponds to slices applied to the two-level indexes respectively. By passing this slice to `.loc[]`, you can choose data that meets the specified date range criteria.

```
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2010-01-09')
selected_data = df.loc[(slice(None), slice(start_date, end_date)), :]
print(selected_data)
```

**Output**

```
                idx_str  idx_dates  data                                                      
blue 2010-01-05    blue 2010-01-05     2                                                      
     2010-01-06    blue 2010-01-06     3                                                      
red  2010-01-05     red 2010-01-05     6                                                      
     2010-01-06     red 2010-01-06     7
```

---

> Question:  I wanted to filter both level of the MultiIndex so the answer also filter the color, why the second , slicing at the end -> , :]

> Answer: You can get 'red' with below code line.
> The last part is for columns filtering. A colon at the end means extract all columns.

```
selected_data = df.loc[(slice('red','red'), slice(start_date, end_date)), 'idx_dates':'data']
```

**Output**

```
                idx_dates  data
red 2010-01-05 2010-01-05     6
    2010-01-06 2010-01-06     7
```

There are many pandas indexing options. Please refers to pandas official document.

> [MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: I like this one cause I can use `pd.Timestamp` directly as opposed to _@quang-hoang_ that require me to build a f-string.
I edited my question as may be it was not very clear, I wanted to filter both level of the MultiIndex so the answer also filter the color, as follow
df.loc[('red, slice(start_date, end_date)), :]
can you edit your answer to reflect it? thanks you :)

Comment: also I don't understand why the second , slicing at the end -> , :]

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the level values with `df.index.get_level_values(level=1)` and mask on that. Or, you can name your index level, then `query` works as expected:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index=['color','time'])
    
start, end = pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-09')
color = 'red'

df.query('@start <= time <= @end & color == @color')
```

Output:

```
                 idx_str  idx_dates  data
color time                               
red   2010-01-05     red 2010-01-05     6
      2010-01-06     red 2010-01-06     7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I edited my question as may be it was not very clear, I wanted to filter both level of the MultiIndex so the answer also filter the color, could you edit? to reflect it? ie `df.query("'2010-01-02' <= time <= '2010-01-09' & color == 'red'"))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
import pandas as pd

idx_str = [
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'red',
    'red',
    'red',
]
idx_date = [
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06'),
    pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10'),
]
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(idx_str, idx_date, data),
    columns=['idx_str', 'idx_dates', 'data'],
)
df.set_index([idx_str, idx_date], drop=True, inplace=True)
filtered_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'):pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06')], :]
print(filtered_df)
               idx_str  idx_dates  data
blue 2010-01-05    blue 2010-01-05     2
     2010-01-06    blue 2010-01-06     3
red  2010-01-05     red 2010-01-05     6
```

Comment: works too :) just I tiiiny bit lengthier than _@taller_excelHome_ solution

Comment: @asiera: It's actually 1 line code. Most of the code is creating your data. Also, I'm not using extra `None`. So, much cleaner and vectorized code.
`filtered_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'):pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06')], :]`

Comment: If you want to filter by color, try this code:
`filtered_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[['blue'], pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05'):pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06')], :]`

Comment: yes, I was talking about the line itself. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with a dictionary, via [pyjanitor's select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function, where the keys of the dictionary are the levels of the multiindex(number or name), and the values are the labels to be selected per level:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.select(rows = {0:'red', 1: slice('2010-01-01', '2010-01-09')})
               idx_str  idx_dates  data
red 2010-01-01     red 2010-01-01     5
    2010-01-05     red 2010-01-05     6
    2010-01-06     red 2010-01-06     7
```